# Selectbox options will not populate div tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I am getting data from a web service that goes through a loop to generate dates for a specific event. When I go through everything the loop works fine but nothing will display in my drop down menu.

This is my JS:

```
function ListMyEventDates(oid,eventname){
    OID = oid;
    $('#eventname').html(eventname); 
    $.getJSON(URL+'func=ListMyEventDates&sid='+SESSIONID+'&oid='+OID, function(data) {
        var eventdate = data.Result.Data;
        var html = '';
        for(var i=0; i<eventdate.length; i++)
        {
            html = html + '<option id="eventdate" value="'+eventdate[i].meeton+'">'+eventdate[i].meeton+'</option>';
        }

        $('#eventdate').html(html);
        $('#eventdate').append(html);
    });
};
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="eventdates">Date:</label>
     <select name="eventdates" data-native-menu="false">
        <div=id="eventdate"></div>
     </select>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append your selectbox like this.

```
$("[name='eventdates']")
   .append($("<option></option>")
   .attr("value",eventdate[i].meeton)
   .text(eventdate[i].meeton));
```